# php drop down list item staying selected

Tags: php, html-select

i have a drop down list in my php code.  Im trying to get the value to stay selected after the page has been submitted using a submit button ( the form action calls another php script however the code block below is in the same php script as the form).  I tried this but it doesn't do what i needed to.  Any suggestions would help.

```
//getting value from database
$dropDownVal=$row['player'];
////
echo "<td bgcolor=#7FFF00><select name='DropDown".$row['_id']."' >;
<option value=\"1\"  if ($dropDownVal==1) selected=\"selected\">Select </option>;
<option value=\"2\"  if ($dropDownVal==2) selected=\"selected\">Johnson</option>;
<option value=\"3\"if ($dropDownVal==3) selected=\"selected\">Reed</option>;
<option value=\"4\"if ($dropDownVal==4) selected=\"selected\">Suggs</option>;
<option value=\"5\"if ($dropDownVal==5) selected=\"selected\">Flacco</option>;
<option value=\"6\"if ($dropDownVal==6) selected=\"selected\">Rice</option>;
</select>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris is essentially correct.

If you are submitting this in a form that uses `POST` variables.

Then if you then modified your logic for setting the `$dropDownVal` to use the `$_POST` variable you should get what you want:

If you're submitting your form via `GET`, just change all references of `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Heres the full code for reference in a single page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['Dropdown'])) {
    $dropDownVal = $_GET['Dropdown'];
} else {
    $dropDownVal = 1;
}
?>
<form method="get" action="testing.php">
    <select name="Dropdown" >;
        <option value="1" <?php if ($dropDownVal==1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Select </option>;
        <option value="2" <?php if ($dropDownVal==2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Johnson</option>;
        <option value="3" <?php if ($dropDownVal==3) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Reed</option>;
        <option value="4" <?php if ($dropDownVal==4) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Suggs</option>;
        <option value="5" <?php if ($dropDownVal==5) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Flacco</option>;
        <option value="6" <?php if ($dropDownVal==6) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Rice</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: ok i see what your saying...one question though ....my script is php so do i have to surround my if statements with "<?php.....?>" or can i leave it like it is?

Comment: to clarify here is the full code as you can use it in a single page.

Comment: the form action calls another page that handles some tasks and returns

Comment: In that case, in the page that handles the processing you will have to make sure you return the dropdown variable when you redirect back to the first page. you can do this via a string concatenation to the url if you are doing a redirect. Eg: <?php header('Location: www.webpage.com/index.php?Dropdown='.$_GET['Dropdown']); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Is this a self-submit script, i.e., the same code renders the form for filling out and also handles the submit? On the submit side you have to read the appropriate GET or POST parameters as the variables don't just hang onto their values before the submit. Instead the submit side is the script executing from line one all over again, without any variables assigned.

Comment: i edited the page..hope i answered your question

Comment: my question would be answered only if you included the submit button code. If it referenced self or whatever it is in php then it would be a self-submit form/script. It's a very good idea in these type scripts, all programs really but even more important in self-submit scripts, to initialize all variables before use. Some webserver cgi setups can give you garbage data in variables from another running copy of the script if you don't initialize to zero or undef or whatever nul value you expect from php.